# mod_rewrite rule not working as it should

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I've used this particular mod_rewrite rule in several other places and it works perfectly as expected.  However, it isn't working here, and for the life of me I cannot see why.

The setup is as follows:

```
www.site.com/villas-in-florida/
```

The .htaccess file is in the directory above, and has the following in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ show-villa.php?id=$1&name=$2&location=$3&state=$4 [L]
```

This should convert the following:

```
http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/show-villa.php?id=1&name=calabay-parc&location=davenport&state=florida
```

Into:

```
http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/1-calabay-parc-davenport-florida
```

But it doesn't, and I'm tearing my actual hair out right now.  Any and all tips would be gratefully appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Problem is using your delimiter hyphen `-` in location i.e. `calabay-parc`

Comment: @anubhava I removed the - from 'name' and tried without it, so calabay-parc became calabayparc, then also tried calabay_parc - no dice on either!

Comment: Hmm still shows `&name=calabay-parc` to me in your target URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont convert:

```
http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/show-villa.php?id=1&name=calabay-parc&location=davenport&state=florida
```

Into:

```
http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/1-calabay-parc-davenport-florida
```

Its the other way around. i.e

It will rewrite (not convert):

```
http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/1-calabay-parc-davenport-florida
```

Into:

```
http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/show-villa.php?id=1&name=calabay-parc&location=davenport&state=florida
```

**You have to use URLs like `http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/1-calabay-parc-davenport-florida` in your `h refs` not `http://www.site.com/villas-in-florida/show-villa.php?id=1&name=calabay-parc&location=davenport&state=florida`. The rewritten URL will not get reflected in the browser.**

Also there is a small mistake in the rewriterule.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ show-villa.php?id=$1&name=$2-$3&location=$4&state=$5 [L]
```

Comment: Accepted, but you broke my site by missing a final ) before +$ :P  I caught it though, thanks a LOT for your answer.  It was taking the 'calabay' and 'parc' as two seperate inputs, as you said.  You're a star!